# reading out all Parent nodes of XML in java

Tags: java, xml, dom, javax.xml

I have a XML as below:

```
<parent>
     <child1>
     </child1>
     <child2>
     </child2>
</parent>
<parent>
     <child3>
     </child3>
     <child4>
     </child4>
</parent>
```

Am able to read the child node values of first parent with the code below:

```
// Get the staff element by tag name directly
            Node PatientVariables = doc.getElementsByTagName("parent").item(0);

            // loop the staff child node
            NodeList patientlist = PatientVariables.getChildNodes();

            for (int i = 0; i < patientlist.getLength(); i++) {
                   Node node = patientlist.item(i);
                 if ("child1".equals(node.getNodeName())) {
                     PatientLastNameValue=node.getTextContent();
                    //System.out.println("The XML value:"+node.getTextContent() );
                   }
```

But I am not able to read the second parent node values (child3 and child4)

Answer (score 3):

XML only allows for one root node. Put your "parent"-nodes under a root node like so:

```
<root>
    <parent>
    ...
    </parent>
    <parent>
    ...
    </parent>
</root>
```

Then interate over the child-nodes of root.

Answer (score 1):

As well as the answer from @Johannes above, This line

```
Node PatientVariables = doc.getElementsByTagName("parent").item(0);
```

Returns only the first `<parent>...</parent>` instance.

You should treat `doc.getElementsByTagName("parent")` as a collection and iterate over it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to go through the xml and add each parent to an array.

```
Node [] PatientVariables = add.doc.getElementsByTagName("parent");
```

You need to loop through the parents, and have a nested loop through the children of each parent.

```
for( int i = 0; i< PatientVariables.length; i++){
  // loop the staff child node
  NodeList patientlist = PatientVariables[i].getChildNodes();

        for (int i = 0; i < patientlist.getLength(); i++) {
               Node node = patientlist.item(i);
        /.../
```

This is a basic idea.